# How can I share state between two custom hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm trying to fetch data from Spotify API. Since I need an access token to do this, I built a custom hook to parse the token from the URL that comes from the server.
I also have another custom hook with the actual request to the API that takes the parsed token as an argument. Both are gathered in a parent hook.

I cannot make this work since the token is never reaching the scope of the request hook so it fails. If I parse the token and make the request within the same hook everything works out just fine. I intended to make a hook for every request since it's not just one, that's why I wanted to pass the token as an argument.

Token custom hook

```
export default () => {
  const [ token, setToken ] = useState('')
  useEffect(() => {
    const { access_token } = queryString.parse(window.location.search)
    return setToken(access_token)
  }, [])
  return token
}
```

Request hook

```
export default function useFetchUserData(token) {
  //state
  const initialUserState = {
    display_name: '',
    external_url: '',
    images: ''
  }
  const [ userData, setUserData ] = useState(initialUserState)
  const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(false)
  const [ isError, setIsError ] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUserData() {
      setIsLoading(true);
      setIsError(false);

      const spotify = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      })
      try {
        const userRes = await spotify('/')
        .then( res => { return res.data });

        setUserData({
          display_name: userRes.display_name,
          external_url: userRes.external_urls.spotify,
          images: userRes.images[0].url
        })
      } catch (error) {
          setIsError(true)
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
    getUserData();
  }, [])

  const data = {
    userData,
    isLoading,
    isError
  }
  return data
}
```

Parent hook

```
export default function Home() {

  const  token = useParseToken()
  const { userData, isLoading, isError } = useFetchUserData(token);

  if (isLoading) return <BarLoader />;
  if (isError) return <div>Oops! something went wrong</div>;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header userData={userData}/>
    </Fragment>  
  )   
}
```

Comment: Hi @FedericoCastro, take a look at the new context API. It sounds like it would be ideal for your use case! Part of hooks was a [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook that makes context easier to work with!

Comment: From your example code, `const { token } = useTokenParser()` might be wrong, should be `const token = useTokenParser()`

Comment: Then inside `useFetchUserData` you should properly handle the case where `token === ""`, cus first call always get that case.

Comment: thanks a lot @hackape, it worked. I got over excited with destructuring.

Comment: thanks @Jared, it may be time to give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens in your case is that you are setting a state in `useEffect` hook in your custom hook to set token. However you return the token from this hook without waiting for the effect to run, so the first time your `useFetchUserData` hook is called, it will receive empty string as a token. To solve this, you must implement the `useFetchUserData` hook to run once token is available or it changed

```
export default function useFetchUserData(token) {
  //state
  const initialUserState = {
    display_name: '',
    external_url: '',
    images: ''
  }
  const [ userData, setUserData ] = useState(initialUserState)
  const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(false)
  const [ isError, setIsError ] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUserData() {
      setIsLoading(true);
      setIsError(false);

      const spotify = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      })
      try {
        const userRes = await spotify('/')
        .then( res => { return res.data });

        setUserData({
          display_name: userRes.display_name,
          external_url: userRes.external_urls.spotify,
          images: userRes.images[0].url
        })
      } catch (error) {
          setIsError(true)
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
    if(token !== '' || token !== null) {
       getUserData();
    }
  }, [token])

  const data = {
    userData,
    isLoading,
    isError
  }
  return data
}
```

Also since `useParseToken` returns the token, you don't need to destructure it while using

```
const token = useParseToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use createContext api of react. 
Save your token as a context. and use it where ever you want.
I think [this repository](https://github.com/Ako92/react-state) will help you.